# Book about a race of giant lizards (possibly aliens) that shape shift into humans and breed with humans

Tags: story-identification, books, shape-shifter

I'm desperately trying to find the title of a book I read years ago. I believe it was written in the 80s(?). I picked it up from a 2nd hand shop about 20 years ago.

It was about a race of giant lizards (possibly aliens) that shape-shift into humans. They bred with humans and lost their ability to do it. The story follows a man who witnessed his family killed by one of the last ones of its kind and is trying to find it.

All I can remember is that it has lumps on its spine when it is in human form and it runs a high-end business.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: What ability did they lose - to shape shift, or to breed with humans?

Comment: They lost the ability to shapeshift as they bred with humans it sort of takes place in the past and present if that makes sense you learn there history through the last one of its kind